# Cannot set Percent_rank() - defaults to 0.0

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, window-functions

I'm trying to SET a column, but the result will end up as 0.0 for each row.
If I use the same syntax (the select part of it) in SELECT, the results display correctly.

```
UPDATE table1
SET ranking = (SELECT
PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY city ORDER BY sales DESC)
from table1
group by store_id)
```

Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery:

```
SELECT PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY city ORDER BY sales DESC)
from table1
group by store_id
```

returns 1 row for each `store_id` and SQLite picks just one and updates with that row's value of `PERCENT_RANK()` all the rows of the table.

You must correlate the subquery with `table1`

```
UPDATE table1
SET ranking = (
  SELECT pr
  FROM (
    SELECT store_id, 
           PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY city ORDER BY sales DESC) pr
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY store_id
  ) t
  WHERE table1.store_id = t.store_id
);
```

Or, if your version of SQLite is 3.33.0 use the `UPDATE...FROM...` syntax:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
SET ranking = t.pr
FROM (
  SELECT store_id, 
         PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY city ORDER BY sales DESC) pr
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY store_id
) t
WHERE t1.store_id = t.store_id;
```